# Converting a working AJAX form to work with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a working html form with jQuery validation and have been submitting the data with AJAX, I am now trying to copy this form in to my own Wordpress theme, but I can't see where I am going wrong in using AJAX in Wordpress.

I am referencing subscribe.js in my headerand this is my form:

```
<div id="subscribe">
    <input type="text" id="emailsub" class="text-input" name="email" placeholder="your email address" />
    <input type="submit" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/send.jpg" alt="Send" width="37" height="27" name="#" id="submitsub" class="contactbutton" />
    <br />
    <!-- Email Validation -->
    <span id="errorSubEmail" class="subError"></span>
    <span id="formSubProgress" class="subProgress"></span>
</div>
```

I am using some jQuery validation, but here is the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://mywebsite.co.uk/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'ajaxfunction',
            email: email,
        }   ,
        success: function(msg) {

            //alert(msg);

            // Check to see if the mail was successfully sent
            if(msg=='Mail sent') {
                // Update the progress bar
                $('.email_wrap #formSubProgress').html('<img src="images/ajax-complete.png" /> Thankyou!').delay(2000).fadeOut(400);

                // Clear the subject field and message textbox
            //  $('.email_wrap #subject').val('');
            //  $('.email_wrap #message').val('');
            } else {
                $('.email_wrap #formSubProgress').html('');
                alert('There was an error sending your email. Please try again.');
            }

            // Activate the submit button
            $('.email_wrap #submitsub').attr("disabled", "");
        },
        error: function(ob,errStr) {
            $('.email_wrap #formSubProgress').html('');
            alert('There was an error sending your email. Please try again.');

            // Activate the submit button
            $('.email_wrap #submitsub').attr("disabled", "");
        }
    });
```

And my functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'add_contact_script');
function add_contact_script() {
wp_register_script('contact', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/subscribe.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
wp_enqueue_script('contact');
}
function ajax_contact() {
if(!isset($_POST['email'])
   ) {
 die('Error: aaaa Missing variables');
}
}

function ajaxfunction() {
//  die("ajaxfunction is called");
if(!isset($_POST['email'])  ) {
    die('Error: Missing variables');
} else {

$email=$_POST['email'];

$to='you@email.com';

$headers = 'The following person has registered to be notified when your webite launches: '."\r\n" ."\r\n" .
    'Email: '.$email."\r\n";

$subject = 'A new person has registered to be updated when you go live';    

if(mail($to, $subject, 
    $headers)) {
    die('Mail sent');
} else {
    die('Error: Mail failed');
}
}
  } 
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxfunction', 'ajaxfunction' );  
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_ ajaxfunction', 'ajaxfunction' );
```

Comment: What happens if you use `jQuery()` instead of the unsupported `$`?

Comment: Thanks but I was using jQuery(document).ready(function($) { which enclosed the whole file including the validation, but even if I do change $ to jQuery for the AJAX there is no change, validation still works but AJAX doesn't

Comment: What exactly isn't working about it? What is the results that you get?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `wp_ajax_ ajaxfunction`. there's a space after the underscore.

also, use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to set your admin-ajax path:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'contact',
    get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/subscribe.js',
    array('jquery'),
    '1.0'
);
wp_localize_script(
    'contact',
    'ContactAjax',
    array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    )
);
```

then in your javascript, use `ContactAjax.ajaxurl`

Comment: Are there not any other problems in my code? Making your change still doesn't get the AJAX to work :(

Comment: You need to provide more details simply saying "doesn't work" makes it impossible to help you.  What doesn't work? Also what event are you attaching your ajax js code to?  I can probably assure you that the ajax isn't even being run.  Please post all your javascript related to the form submission and validation.  Also attach your wp_enque_script to wp_enqueue_scripts hook not init.

Comment: Agree that you need to confirm the ajax code is even being fired.  You should be able to see whether the ajax is run by looking in your console.